# jQuery click next button

Tags: jquery, button

I have multiple buttons on a page and I want to simulate a click on the NEXT button.

```
$('input, select').keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13)
    //$('input[type*=button]').click();
    $(this).next('input[type*=button]').click();
});
```

Html:

```
<tr>
    <td class="cell">
        <input type="text" name="domain" class="entryfield" value="http://">
    </td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td class="cell" align="right" colspan="2">
        <input type="button" class="button" value="Get IP" id="submitDomain"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The commented code works, but that clicks all buttons on the page.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It depends on what your HTML looks like...

Comment: Hey @AndrewWhitaker, could you explain a little more please? Would I have to use .parents() ?

Comment: You are probably looking for the following button. But `next('somethinghere')` only is a conditional statement. It will not automatically give you the following button. Just, if the next *is* a button, it will perform next.

Comment: @Prash: It really depends on your markup. Could you post a sample?

Comment: I see. I've also tried the following: $('input[type*=button]').next().click();

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker Here's an example. Apologies for ugly code, I didn't write the HTML (only backend).

Comment: `<td class="cell"><input type="text" name="domain" class="entryfield" value="http://"></td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td class="cell" align="right" colspan="2"><input type="button" class="button" value="Get IP" id="submitDomain"/></td>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your markup:

```
$("input, select").keydown(function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").next().find("input:button").click();
});
```

Basically, find the [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) table row, then find its immediate sibling `tr`. Inside that `tr` [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find) the button you'd like to click.

Next finds the *immediately following sibling*, so calling [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next) on the `input` that the event occurred on wouldn't actually find anything.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/N3WBP/

Comment: Thanks for this, wasn't aware how the next() function works. This HTML is a bitch to work with. Once more, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(this).next().click();
```

like here: http://api.jquery.com/next/